# Swagger description for request part

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

is it possible to have a request DTO model described in Swagger-UI if it was annotated by `@RequestPart`, not `@RequestBody` ?? I have an API which uploads a MultipartFile and additionally I have send a JSON with config at the same time. To make it work I had to use `@RequestPart` and swagger documentation seems not to handle it at all - in UI instead of full model description I have only "formData" object and that's all.

```
 public void addPhoto(@RequestParam(FILE_PARAM) MultipartFile file,
                      @RequestPart("config") ConfigDTO configDTO) {
         //code goes here
}
```

Dependencies I use:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```